# Use csv file instead of json file in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to use a csv file instead of a json file in this example:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Any idea for loading a csv instead of a json file?

Comment: Tried `d3.csv`?

Comment: Or d3.dsv for other delimiters

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is way more complicated than it seems, and I suggest you that you leave the data file as JSON. The reason is this: the JSON file in your question contains **nested** data.

Here is an explanation:

Apparently, the only difference between loading a CSV file and loading a JSON file is the request function:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(data){
    //code here
)}
```

... for a JSON and:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data){
    //code here
)}
```

... for a CSV.

But there is more. Besides the fact that `d3.csv` accepts an accessor (row) function and `d3.json` does not, `d3.json` loads the data **as it is**. On the other hand, `d3.csv` parses the file according to the columns, creating an array of objects.

Thus, if you have this CSV:

```
city,population,area
New York,3400,210
Melbourne,1200,350
Tokyo,5200,125
Paris,800,70
```

... it will be parsed to this array:

```
[{
    "city": "New York",
    "population": "3400",
    "area": "210"
}, {
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "population": "1200",
    "area": "350"
}, {
    "city": "Tokyo",
    "population": "5200",
    "area": "125"
}, {
    "city": "Paris",
    "population": "800",
    "area": "70"
}]
```

And here comes the problem: As you can see, there is no nested data in the array created by `d3.csv`. All the objects are side by side in the array.

However, the data object in Bostock's code you linked is way different:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      //...
```

As you can see, you have arrays inside objects inside arrays inside objects...

So, to recreate the nested JSON in your question, you'll have to create an additional column, specifying who is parent of who and who is child of who:

```
name,value,parentOf
foo,42,bar
bar,53,baz
...
```

Then, *after* parsing this CSV, you'll have to *stratify* it, using [stratify()](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#stratify):

```
var nestedData = d3.stratify()
    .id(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.parentOf; })
    (data);
```

As you can see, those are complicated steps.

Therefore, as a general rule: if you have nested data as a JSON file, just use `d3.json`, which loads the data as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `d3.csv()` instead of `d3.json()`. See [D3's documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv).